# How to export directory from svn https address? Destination directory exists?

Tags: svn, export

I am not very familiar with svn so I have a very basic question. I just want to copy an entire directory to local. So I'm not interested in creating any kind of branches to work in at this time.

I've tried the following:

```
svn export https://.../directory/ /home/myself/folder/
```

and it returns "Destination directory exists".

I'm not really sure how to copy this over?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`--force`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/#svn.ref.svn.sw.force) or better specify another directory.

BTW, here is the complete wording of the error:

```
svn: E155000: Destination directory exists; please remove the directory or use --force to overwrite
svn: E155000: 'MyFolder' already exists
```

Comment: Hello, forgive my confusion here, if I use force it will only replace *that* last directory not the parent directory?